# Calculating a relative Prime of a number in JAVA?

Tags: java, math, primes, prime-factoring

I am working on a program in which I have calculated a number of type `long` after applying some calculations according to my algorithm. Now, I have to find a relative prime to this number that I have generated. How can I do this? I know that if two numbers are relative prime then their `GCD == 1` but in this case I don't have another number. I have only one number which is getting generated in my program and I need to calculate a relative prime number for this number.

**Edit**

Condition for generating relative prime is such that:

`1 < relative prime < generated Number`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### A simple way to get a relative prime:

> Now, I have to find a relative prime to this number

For whole number `n` where `n>2` it is always true that `n` and `n-1` are relatively prime. So assuming `n` isn't 2 or less, simply have `n-1` be the output, as it is guaranteed relatively prime. If `n` equals 2 then your condition is impossible.

### Non-trivial relative primes

You can always actually calculate GCDs if you want a non-trivial solution. Use Euclid's method as follows:

```
long findGCD(long l1, long l2) {
    //end recursion
    if(l2 == 0){
        return number1;
    }
    return findGCD(l2, l1%l2);
}
```

and use a while loop to try all numbers starting at `n+2` until you get a GCD of 1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have one condition that is needed to be fulfilled. I forgot to add that in my question, according to which the relative prime should be smaller that my generated number.

Comment: @UsamaSarwar Simple. Assuming the number is greater than 3, take that number **minus** one. It will work in any case. If the number is 2 or lower it would never work.